# ConversionService not working in Unit Test (spring 3.2)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit4, mockito

I hace a Web application working good. Now I'm trying to write unit test for it. My webapp has the following conversionService

```
<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
        <property name="converters">
            <list>
                <bean class="....Class1ToStringConverter"/>
                <bean class="....StringToClass1Converter"/>
            </list>
        </property>
</bean>
<mvc:annotation-driven  conversion-service="conversionService" />
```

Which works nice and when I do a request to

```
/somepath/{class1-object-string-representation}/xx
```

everything works as expected (string got interpreted as Class1 object).

My problem is trying to write a unit test to my controller. The conversionService is just not used and spring just tell me

```
Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [Class1]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

My Test so far:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml", "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jpm-servlet.xml"})
@WebAppConfiguration()
public class GeneralTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext ctx;
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    private TestDAO testDAO = org.mockito.Mockito.mock(TestDAO.class);

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        Mockito.reset(testDAO);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(ctx).build();
    }

@Test
public void testList() throws Exception {
    final Test first = new Test(1L, "Hi", 10, new Date(), true);
    final Test second = new Test(2L, "Bye", 50, new Date(), false);
    first.setTest(second);

    when(testDAO.list()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(first, second));

    mockMvc.perform(get("/jpm/class1-id1"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(view().name("list"))
            .andExpect(forwardedUrl("/WEB-INF/jsp/list.jsp"));
}
```

What Im missing? Thanks

Comment: Did you include conversionService in either "applicationContext.xml" or "jpm-servlet.xml"? Does any clue in log? The possibility I could think of is that spring did not find your conversionService and used a default one, so what about changing "conversionService" as "conversionService1"?

Comment: conversionService is in jpm-servlet.xml file but yes, for some unknow reaseon, Test context uses a default conversionService instead of mine :( looks like its ignoring <mvc:annotation-driven  conversion-service="conversionService" />. I renamed it but not helped

Comment: Could you inspect your log (set level to debug), there should be something like "defining beans [conversionService1,mvcContentNegotiationManager,", do you find other conversionService being created?

Comment: Well yes, it is there. 2013/09/04 15:53:15 [main] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1fa62593: defining beans [..., conversionService,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#1,...]

Comment: if this question is answered please approve answer

Answer (score 6):

Mock Converter Like this,

```
  GenericConversionService conversionService = new GenericConversionService();
  conversionService.addConverter(new StringToClass1Converter());



Deencapsulation.setField(FIXTURE, conversionService);
```

Answer (score 3):

This post is a little outdated, but still one of the first Google results, when searching for this problem.

So here is an Update for **Spring Framework 5**.

When you do configure a WebMvc context like documented in the [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-config), you write something like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

However, this is *not* loaded in a JUnit context! God knows why. But you need to declare your configuration class like this:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

So remove the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation and extend from another class as described above. You likely don't have to change anything else.
Then your `addFormatters` method is also called in your unit tests.

This is very unintuitive and odd. But it's true. You can debug the spring-test source code with breakpoints and see, that all the other methods of the `WebMvcConfigurer` interface are called, but `addFormatters` is not. Maybe they have just forgotten to call it or they have other "reasons". By extending from `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` every method is called as desired and your JUnit tests succeed.

In particular, this code gets eventually executed:

```
@Bean
public FormattingConversionService mvcConversionService() {
    FormattingConversionService conversionService = new DefaultFormattingConversionService();
    addFormatters(conversionService);
    return conversionService;
}
```

Honestly, I do not know what exactly fails, when just implementing the interface as described in the Spring documentation.

Comment: Voted up because it's a lot more relevant now. However, I found adding `@EnableWebMvc` to my Configuration class fixed it (instead of on the test), despite using the `WebMvcConfigurer`. Perhaps it's been fixed since.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. If you are trying to test a single controller, you could try the following:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml", "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jpm-servlet.xml"})
@WebAppConfiguration()
public class GeneralTest {

  @Autowired
  private WebApplicationContext ctx;
  @Autowired
  private FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean conversionService;

  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Mock
  private TestDAO testDAO;

  /* The following assumes you are injecting your DAO into your controller
   * If you are using a service layer (most likely), you should 
   * inject your DAO into your service and your service into your controller.
   */
  @InjectMocks
  private YourControllerClass controllerToTest;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
      MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

      //get the conversion service from the factory bean
      FormattingConversionService cs = conversionService.getObject();
      Mockito.reset(testDAO);

      //setup MockMvc using the conversion service
      mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controllerToTest)
            .setConversionService(cs)
            .build();
  }

  @Test
  public void testList() throws Exception {
    final Test first = new Test(1L, "Hi", 10, new Date(), true);
    final Test second = new Test(2L, "Bye", 50, new Date(), false);
    first.setTest(second);

    when(testDAO.list()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(first, second));

    mockMvc.perform(get("/jpm/class1-id1"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(view().name("list"))
            .andExpect(forwardedUrl("/WEB-INF/jsp/list.jsp"));
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this is an old thread but like me, there'll be others that're going to stumble across this in the future after having spent several hours troubleshooting why their custom converter does not get invoked.

The solution proposed by @Mariano D'Ascanio isn't adequate in cases where there're simply no controllers, at least not the ones that you wrote, like when you're using Spring JPA. `MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup` requires at least one controller to be passed to the constructor so you can't use that for such cases. The way to get around that is by injecting the `org.springframework.core.convert.converter.ConverterRegistry` or better yet, it's subclass `org.springframework.core.convert.converter.FormatterRegistry` and then in a `@PostContruct` method, register your custom converter/formatter as shown below:

```
@PostConstruct
void init() {
    formatterRegistry.removeConvertible(String.class, OffsetDateTime.class);

    formatterRegistry.addFormatter(customOffsetDateTimeFormatter);
    formatterRegistry.addConverter(customOffsetDateTimeConverter);
}
```

The trick is to inject the `ConverterRegistry` using a name, not a type, because for web tests, there're two converter registries, default and mvc. Spring tests use the default converter, so that's the one you need.

```
// GOTCHA ALERT: There's also a mvcConversionService; tests DO NOT use that
@Resource(name = "defaultConversionService")
private FormatterRegistry formatterRegistry;
```

Hope this helps.